# Bind an event handler to multiple element variables in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, element

I want to bind multiple elements that are defined as a variable. I know this is possible:

```
$('selector1, selector2').bind(...)
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
$($element1, $element2, $element3).bind(...)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not the best, but just for fun, you could do `$($element1.selector + ", " + $element2.selector + ", " + $element3.selector)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to add them to one result set:

```
$element1.add($element2).add($element3).bind(...)
```

Or for an arbitrary number of elements:

```
var elems = [$element1, $element2, $element3, ...];
var $result = $();

$.each(elems, function() {
    $result = $result.add(this);
});

$result.bind(...);
```

Or with `Array.reduce`:

```
[$element1, $element2, $element3, ...].reduce(function($result, $elem) {
    return $result.add($elem);
}, $()).bind(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [add()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add);

```
var $all = $element1.add($element2).add($element3).bind( ... ); //.add(...)
```

Comment: I assumed (probably wrongly) that the elements where js objects, I updated my answer just in case

Comment: Test it. jQuery wraps array objects differently than it wraps DOM objects.

Comment: It won't work with jQuery instances, I know, I should have mention that. I hope the edit ammends that

Comment: The first one was considering non jquery objects. But you're right, and it's confusing, so I'll edit the answer and I'll leave the last part. But just to clarify, your fiddle it's missing the `0` in the get methods, that's why it didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/Uj9hk/3/